# Trapping error messages with arcpy.getmessage issue

Tags: arcpy, error

I am trying to capture an error with arcpy.getmessage(2) within a try/except statement but when it fails it tells me the issue is with the getmessage, it is not returning the error that occurred in the try part. This is what I have setup to capture the error message...

```
try:
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(Flow_Arrow, Flow_Arrow__2_, "", "0", "0", "0")
    print "Flow Arrow Updated"
    print "Flow Direct Feature Set Updated"
except:
    print "Error"
    print arcpy.getmessage(2)
```

I know it has got to be something simple I am just overlooking, I tried arcpy.getmessage(), and arcpy.getmessage(0), I went with the (2) because I was googling the issue it was one of the proposed solutions.

Comment: Shouldn't it be arcpy.GetMessage(2)? Python is a case sensitive language so getmessage isn't the same as GetMessage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python is case sensitive, GetMessage should be capitalized

```
try:
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(Flow_Arrow, Flow_Arrow__2_, "", "0", "0", "0")
    print "Flow Arrow Updated"
    print "Flow Direct Feature Set Updated"
except:
    print "Error"
    print arcpy.GetMessage(2)
```

Comment: Bloody hell! Thanks guys, I am going to go and put my dunce cap on.